# Python Pandas Filter Column by Multiple Criteria

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like this:

```
 A     B        D
 d     151     M
 d     152     a
 d     153     M
 d     161     z
 d     164     M
 d     169     g
 d     178     g
 d     173     e
 d     176     j
 d     605     j
 d     603     d
 d     607     e
 d     905     j
 d     903     d
 d     907     e
```

I want to filter it based on the values of column B. Specifically i want the values of column B that begins with 15, 16 and 60. My dataframe would be reduced to:

```
 A     B        D
 d     151     M
 d     152     a
 d     153     M
 d     161     z
 d     164     M
 d     169     g
 d     605     j
 d     603     d
 d     607     e
```

So far i've been unsuccessful to achieve this result. Which would be the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need convert to `str` first and select first `2` values which are compared with [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html) and filter with [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
print (df.B.astype(str).str[:2])
0     15
1     15
2     15
3     16
4     16
5     16
6     17
7     17
8     17
9     60
10    60
11    60
12    90
13    90
14    90
Name: B, dtype: object

print (df[df.B.astype(str).str[:2].isin(['15','16','60'])])
    A    B  D
0   d  151  M
1   d  152  a
2   d  153  M
3   d  161  z
4   d  164  M
5   d  169  g
9   d  605  j
10  d  603  d
11  d  607  e
```

Another solution is use [`contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) with custom regex - `^` means start of string and `|` or:

```
L = [15,16,90]
val = '|'.join(['^' + str(x) for x in L])
print (val)
^15|^16|^90
print (df[df.B.astype(str).str.contains(val)])
    A    B  D
0   d  151  M
1   d  152  a
2   d  153  M
3   d  161  z
4   d  164  M
5   d  169  g
12  d  905  j
13  d  903  d
14  d  907  e
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> df[df['B'].map(lambda x: str(x[:2]) in ['15', '16', '60'])]
    A    B  D
0   d  151  M
1   d  152  a
2   d  153  M
3   d  161  z
4   d  164  M
5   d  169  g
9   d  605  j
10  d  603  d
11  d  607  e
```

Comment: A bit danger, if in column B is `None` or `NaN` - get error.

Comment: @jezrael Updated to address None or NaN

Comment: only I think if in column B is `None` or `NaN` get error - so solution works only if is 100% sure never get it. So better is use `str.contains` or `isin` which nice handling it.

Comment: @jezrael yea right, can you explain me `df.B.astype(str).str[:2]` i got it till df.B.astype(str) it typecasting it to str. but str[:2] i don't get it. as str is built in python.

Comment: It is called [indexing with str](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/text.html#indexing-with-str)

Comment: @jezrael thanks for the info, I got it now. I just started learning pandas 2-3 days ago.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143560/discussion-between-hackaholic-and-jezrael).